# Nativescript 6 - tap event not firing on child element

Tags: nativescript

The tap event code attached to the StackLayout works in Android, but not in iOS.

XML:

```html
          <GridLayout id="outmost" row="2">
            <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*, *">
                <StackLayout class="btn btn-filled" col="0" margin="0 7 0 15" tap="login">
                        <Label text="LOG IN" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="middle" class="btn-text" />                        
                </StackLayout>
            </GridLayout>    
        </GridLayout>
```

The tap event does not fire on iOS.  If I move tap="login" to the topmost GridLayout(id=outmost), the event fires.  It seems to me that the event is captured by the GridLayout#outmost and not propagated down to the children.

This started happening after I migrated the app to NS 6.

Here is my package.json:

```html
{
  "name": "app",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.company.app",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.0.1"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.0.1"
    }
  },
  "description": "App",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nativescript-appversion": "^1.4.2",
    "nativescript-geolocation": "5.1.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "1.3.0",
    "nativescript-loading-indicator": "2.4.0",
    "nativescript-local-notifications": "3.1.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "9.0.4",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.0.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "author": ""
}
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you submit a Playground sample to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: dpdragnev the event should be fired - in fact, if you have tap gestures for all layouts they all will be fired - here is a demo Playground https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=wvzKkL&v=2

Comment: Thanks, @NickIliev.  I am wondering why my app does not behave the same way. Can you think of any possible reason?

Comment: After some more testing I found the issue.  It was my fault.  I had another StackLayout (not included in the snipped above) that was overlapping the button.  Sorry to waste your time.